# Python - How do you detect that a module has been loaded by custom loader?

Tags: python, python-3.3

Before Python-3.3, I detected that a module was loaded by a custom loader with `hasattr(mod, '__loader__')`.
After Python-3.3, all modules have the `__loader__` attribute regardless of being loaded by a custom loader.

Python-2.7, 3.2:

```
>>> import xml
>>> hasattr(xml, '__loader__')
False
```

Python-3.3:

```
>>> import xml
>>> hasattr(xml, '__loader__')
True
>>> xml.__loader__
<_frozen_importlib.SourceFileLoader object at ...>
```

How do I detect that a module was loaded by a custom loader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple check for the existence of the `__loader__` attribute is no longer sufficient in Python 3.3. [PEP 302](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0302) requires that all loaders store their information in the `__loader__` attribute of a module.

I would add an additional check for the `type(module.__loader__)`to see if the module was loaded with the custom loader (or in a list of loaders) you are searching for:

```
>>> CUSTOM_LOADERS = [MyCustomLoader1, MyCustomLoader2]
>>> type(xml.__loader__) in CUSTOM_LOADERS
True
```

This may be bad from a maintenance point-of-view, in that you will have to keep the list of custom loaders up to date. Another similar approach may be creating a list of the standard built-in loaders and change the check to be `not in` STANDARD_LOADERS. This will still have the maintenance issue though.

Comment: Thanks. In my case, I can not get CUSTOM_LOADERS list beforehand.
STANDARD_LOADERS is better, but it is bit difficult to prepare in standard procedure.

<code>
    >>> import importlib._bootstrap
    >>> loader_classes = tuple(x[0] for x in importlib._bootstrap._get_supported_file_loaders())
    >>> isinstance(os.__loader__, tuple(loader_classes))
    True

    >>> isinstance(sys.__loader__, tuple(loader_classes))
    False
    >>> sys.__loader__
    <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
</code>

Comment: I think `STANDARD_LOADERS = file_loaders + (BuiltinImporter + FrozenImporter + zipimporter)`.